# React Native ListView for Highscore in a game, how to highlight a speficic row

Tags: javascript, android, json, listview, react-native

Im trying to program a Highscore-Screen for a Quiz-Game with a ListView which gives me all the players with their scores. Actually I want to highlight my points, because in the ListView are no nicknames, just ID and points from every Player.
The Highscore.js Screen has a connection to a websocket which send me a JSON like this :

```
    {"Finish":"true","Scores":{"48046":0,"48056":2}}
```

In this JSON you see if the Game is finished, and then the always changing ID and score for a Player. Here are two Player, Player 46046 has 0 Points and Player 486056 has 2 Points. I don't know which one is my ID, because the websocket server generates the ID. Only by comparing my points to this JSON-Message I get to know my ID. Here is the ListView which I have:

```
    <ListView
                dataSource={
                    this.ds.cloneWithRows(
                        this.state.sortable
                    )
                }
                renderRow={(rowData)=> {
                    return (
                        <View style={styles.row}>
                            <Text style={styles.rowText}> Spieler: {rowData.toString().substring(0,6)}</Text><Text style={styles.scoreText}>  Score: {rowData.toString().substring(6,7)}</Text>
                        </View>
                    )
                }}

            />
```

I didn't know how to get access to the ID and the Value in the rowData correctly. When I wrote just rowData it gave me the ID and Score attached, so
"48046":0 became 480460, that's why I used substring. If you can teach me a better method, please tell me!

The next and most important thing is, that I don't know to get the row selected and highlighted which is me. I know my score, but how can I generally highlight my row? For example if I have 2 points I'm the player 48056. I integrated a counter which I put into my WebsocketController, it's just a variable which counts my point and it is accessable from every component. The Websocket-Server generates for every game a new ID for every Player. How can I highlight me? 
It would be enough for me just to change the backgroundColor from my row.

Here is my code:

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';
    import {  View, Text, ListView, StyleSheet, KeyboardAvoidingView, Image,                 TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
    import WebsocketController from './WebsocketController';


    class HighScore extends Component {

        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
            this.ds = new ListView.DataSource({rowHasChanged: (r1, r2) => r1 !== r2});
            this.state =({
                sortable : [],
            })
        }

        async onButtonPressed() {
            console.log("HighScore ButtonPressed");
            var newGame = new WebsocketController();

            this.props.navigation.navigate('StartGame');
        }

        static navigationOptions = {
            header: null
        };

        componentWillMount(){
            const {params} = this.props.navigation.state;
            console.log("params",params.Scores);

            for (var id in params.Scores){
                this.setState= ({
                    sortable : this.state.sortable.push([id, params.Scores[id]])
                })
            }
            this.state.sortable.sort(function(a,b){ 
                return b[1]-a[1];
            });

            for (var i = 0 ; i <this.state.sortable.length; i++){
                console.log(this.state.sortable[i]);
            }
        }

        render() {
           var wsc = new WebsocketController();
            wsc.close();
            return(
            <KeyboardAvoidingView style = {styles.container}
                        behaviour=" padding"
            >
                <View style = {styles.logoContainer}>

                    <Image
                        style={styles.logo}
                        source={require('../../images/Breezeicons-actions-22-games-highscores.svg.png')} //Logo for QuizGame
                    />
                </View>

                <View style = {styles.listContainer}>
                    <ListView
                        dataSource={
                            this.ds.cloneWithRows(
                                this.state.sortable
                            )}
                        renderRow={(rowData)=> {
                            return (
                                <View style={styles.row}>
                                    <Text style={styles.rowText}> Spieler: {rowData.toString().substring(0,6)}</Text><Text style={styles.scoreText}>  Score: {rowData.toString().substring(6,7)}</Text>
                                </View>
                            )
                        }}
                    />

                </View>
                <View style = {styles.listContainer}>
                    <Text style={styles.yourScoreText}> Your score is {wsc.getPoints()} ! </Text>
                </View>

                <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
                    <TouchableOpacity style = {styles.buttonContainer}
                        onPress = {this.onButtonPressed.bind(this)}
                    >
                    <Text style = {styles.buttonText}> Start new Game </Text>
                    </TouchableOpacity>
                </View>
            </KeyboardAvoidingView>
            );
        }
    }

    var styles = StyleSheet.create({
        container: {
            justifyContent: 'flex-start',
            alignItems: 'center', 
            backgroundColor: '#daa520', 
            flex:1,
        },
        heading:{
            color: '#800000', 
            width: 300, 
            textAlign: 'center',
            justifyContent:'center',
            padding:10,
            fontSize:28,
            flex:1,
            fontFamily:'verdana'
        },
        logoContainer: {
            justifyContent: 'flex-start', 
            alignItems: 'center', 
            backgroundColor: '#daa520', 
            flex:1,
            width:  880,
            height: 440,
        },
        buttonContainer:{
            backgroundColor: '#800000',
            marginBottom: 20,
            width: 340,
            height: 50,
        },
        buttonText: {
            textAlign: 'center',
            textAlignVertical: 'center',
            color:'#FFF',
            fontWeight: '800',
            marginTop: 18,
        },
        logo: {
            width:  880, 
            height: 440, 
            resizeMode: 'contain',
            marginTop: 5,
            flex: 1,
        },
        row: {
            flexDirection:'row',
            justifyContent: 'center',
            padding: 10,
            marginBottom:3,
            backgroundColor: '#f4f4f4',
        },
        scoreText:{
            textAlign: 'left',
            textAlignVertical: 'center',
            color: '#010001',
            fontWeight: '800',
            marginBottom: 1,
        },
        rowText: {
            textAlign: 'left',
            textAlignVertical: 'center',
            color: '#800000',
            fontWeight: '800',
            marginBottom: 1,
        },
        imageContainer: {
            flex: 1,
            width:  440, 
            height: 220,
            marginTop: 5
        },
        listContainer:{
            flex:1
        },
        titleStyle:{
            textAlign: 'left',
            textAlignVertical: 'center',
            color:'#FFF', 
            fontWeight: '900',
            marginBottom: 20,
            fontSize: 20,
        },
        yourScoreText: {
            textAlign: 'left',
            textAlignVertical: 'center',
            color: '#800000',
            fontWeight: '800',
            marginBottom: 1,
            fontSize: 35
        }
    });
        export default HighScore;
```

Thank you very much for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to pass the current player's id to the listview. Once you have the player id, you can conditionally set the style on the view returned by `renderRow`. For example, say the id is passed in `this.props.playerId`:

```
<View style={rowData.toString().substring(0,6) == this.props.playerId ? styles.row : styles.highlightedRow}>
    <Text style={styles.rowText}> Spieler: {rowData.toString().substring(0,6)}</Text><Text style={styles.scoreText}>  Score: {rowData.toString().substring(6,7)}</Text>
</View>
```

Of course this means you will have to define the styling for 'highlightedRow' in styles.

Comment: if i try this it higlights my whole ListView

Comment: Double check your condition and make sure it's true only for the rowData object for the row you want highlighted